# Conditionally filter rows in one df for specific columns which are common to subset of another df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Lets assume a df1

```
 df1 = pd.DataFrame(
{'col1': {0: 500.0, 1: 500.0, 2: 833.3, 3: 500.0, 4: 833.3, 5: 500.0, 6: 833.3},
'col2': {0: 1833.3, 1: 1000.0, 2: 1833.3, 3: 2666.7, 4: 1833.3, 5: 3500.0, 6: 1000.0},
'col3': {0: 250.0, 1: 250.0, 2: 30.0, 3: 30.0, 4: 30.0, 5: 103.3, 6: 176.7},
'col4': {0: 3.4, 1: 4.0, 2: 2.2, 3: 3.4, 4: 2.2, 5: 4.0, 6: 3.4},
'col5': {0: 0.25, 1: 0.15, 2: 0.1, 3: 0.25, 4: 0.25, 5: 0.1, 6: 0.1},
'col6': {0: 364, 1: 937, 2: 579, 3: 313, 4: 600, 5: 49, 6: 13}})
```

And a df2

```
 df2 = pd.DataFrame(
{'col1': {0: 833.3, 1: 500.0, 2: 500.0, 3: 500.0, 4: 500.0, 5: 500.0, 6: 500.0, 7: 833.3, 8: 500.0, 9: 833.3, 10: 500.0, 11: 500.0, 12: 833.3, 13: 833.3, 14: 833.3},
'col2': {0: 1833.3, 1: 1000.0, 2: 1833.3, 3: 3500.0, 4: 3500.0, 5: 1000.0, 6: 2666.7, 7: 1833.3, 8: 2666.7, 9: 1000.0, 10: 2666.7, 11: 2666.7, 12: 1000.0, 13: 1833.3, 14: 1833.3},
'col3': {0: 30.0, 1: 250.0, 2: 250.0, 3: 103.3, 4: 176.7, 5: 103.3, 6: 30.0, 7: 103.3, 8: 30.0, 9: 176.7, 10: 250.0, 11: 103.3, 12: 30.0, 13: 30.0, 14: 250.0},
'col4': {0: 2.2, 1: 4.0, 2: 3.4, 3: 4.0, 4: 2.2, 5: 2.8, 6: 2.8, 7: 2.8, 8: 3.4, 9: 3.4, 10: 2.8, 11: 2.8, 12: 3.4, 13: 2.2, 14: 2.8}, 
'col5': {0: 0.25, 1: 0.15, 2: 0.25, 3: 0.1, 4: 0.2, 5: 0.15, 6: 0.15, 7: 0.25, 8: 0.25, 9: 0.1, 10: 0.15, 11: 0.1, 12: 0.15, 13: 0.1, 14: 0.2}})
```

What is the most pythonic way to drop the rows in df2 where col1 and col2 and col3 and col4 (and coln for that matter) have the same values as the respective columns of df1?
I don't want to merge the dataframes, only drop any rows in df2 (might be multiple) where the row tuple over the interest columns is the same in both dfs.

I have only come up with how to do this using :

```
new_df = df2.loc[df2[col1].isin(df1[col1]) &
              df2[col2].isin(df1[col2]) &
              df2[col3].isin(df1[col3]) &
              df2[col4].isin(df1[col4]) &
              df2[col5].isin(df1[col5]) ]
```

which is a bit cumbersome for larger datasets and for more columns.

Any ideas for a better way?

Comment: I have tried to ask for clarifications. For the moment I don't think that I have found the right answer to this yet.

Comment: I see that now. The main problem is we can't *reproduce* your error. A description is great, but what would *really* help is if you were able to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50177258/edit) your question with an example demonstrating the problem (either Wen's or mine, doesn't matter whose). I've tested my solution with your data and it seems to work.

Comment: i have tried to make the data in a format that is easy to reproduce. Hopefully this helps to find a better solution

Answer (score 2):

You can using `isin`,before doing that we need create a key using all value from col1~ coln(convert to str and paste together)

```
df2[~df2[df1.columns].astype(str).sum(1).isin(df1.astype(str).sum(1))]
```

Comment: This fails if dtypes differ so in OP `df1.loc[0,'col1'].astype(str)` is `'500'` but `df2.loc[0,'col1'].astype(str)` is `'500.0'` which won't match with `isin`

Comment: For this specific case this works: `df2[~df2[df1.columns].astype(str).sum(1).isin(df1.astype(np.float).astype(str).sum(1))]`

Comment: @Dan thanks for the suggestions. But will this also work if df1 has more columns than the ones we would like to compare on?
Also will this still work if the values in one or any of the columns are strings? So we would be comparing a mix of floats/integers and strings

Comment: Would it be a solution to extract a tuple of the values from df2 to a list and then compare that to the values of the columns in question in df1? Ideally though we should be able to do this fully in pandas

Comment: @RedSparrow nope isin is the function from pandas

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set_index` combined with [`pd.Index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) to extract your result:

```
idx = df2.set_index(list(df2)).index\
         .difference(df1.set_index(list(df1)).index)

res = df2.set_index(list(df2)).loc[idx].reset_index()
```

The benefit of this method is it doesn't require numeric to string conversion.

Comment: will this also work if we have a mix of strings and floats as values in each of the columns? Also, why should we reset index? I only need to drop the rows

Comment: We need to `reset_index` so that the index become rows again! A dataframe with an index and no data is probably no use to you. It should work with strings and floats, but you should test with your data.

Comment: ok some comments on this. First, it seems to work. But I am loosing my column names (they become level_0, 1 etc etc) when there is no match between the two df values. The other issue is that this seems to be a bit slow. Is there a more efficient way to do it?